# WiFi authentication times out

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora, wpa-supplicant

Since today I have this very annoying issue that the WiFi on my HP ProBook is not authenticating anymore. I haven't changed any settings and my mobile phone connects to the WiFi fine. Also trying another WiFi access point (in fact, my mobile phone hotspot) doesn't work.

The scan seems to work, as SSIDs show up fine. Also, if no key is provided, it nicely asks for it. But then, I see this in `dmesg`:

```
[ 1854.199036] wlo1: authenticate with 92:68:c3:f4:ec:3a
[ 1854.201743] wlo1: send auth to 92:68:c3:f4:ec:3a (try 1/3)
[ 1854.275690] wlo1: send auth to 92:68:c3:f4:ec:3a (try 2/3)
[ 1854.334745] wlo1: send auth to 92:68:c3:f4:ec:3a (try 3/3)
[ 1854.393245] wlo1: authentication with 92:68:c3:f4:ec:3a timed out
```

I had the issue on Fedora 20, so I upgraded to 21. Problem remains the same. Even updated to 22 beta, with `wpa_supplicant`, version 2.3. Same problem.

In my attempts to resolve this issue I found some extras:

- The adapter works fine in Windows 7, so my router and the hardware is fine.
- I tried to use `wpa_cli`, but I get the message it cannot connect.
- The `ctrl_interface` in `wpa_supplicant.conf` is not created

In the `wpa_supplicant.log`, I get this:

```
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:01:df:c2:fb (SSID='MYSSID' freq=2467 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:01:df:c2:fb (SSID='MYSSID' freq=2467 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:01:df:c2:fb (SSID='MYSSID' freq=2467 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:01:df:c2:fb (SSID='MYSSID' freq=2467 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MYSSID" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

**Update** Even access points without any encryption are not associated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2235768):

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 wd_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot, and it works again.

Comment: to add some clarification here the 802.11n/ac part can be dodgy disable them

Comment: Curious why you didn't just say 'add this to the conf file' instead of the `tee` construct?

Comment: @gws, no idea exactly, but this is a quote from the source, plus this way people can easily copy and paste it into their terminal, instead of firing up an editor.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is what got me out of trouble after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04LTS, sadly. My Thinkpad laptop would no longer connect to a TP-Link router where it was still working with another router running OpenWRT. HTH.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 'can be dodgy disable them'? That adds more confusion for me, assuming this is bad grammar/typo

Comment: 5 years later you solved a 5-months-long problem for me. THANK YOU! Btw, rebooting might not be necessary, simply restart the iwd service `sudo systemctl restart iwd`.

Comment: @NoahBoegli did you confuse the answer? This one doesn't mention `iwd`, the other one does.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Nope, but changing the parameters of iwlwifi fixed my issues with my iwd installation. I can't update the comment, and when re-reading it back one year later it does not make sense to talk about iwd in a wpa_supplicant thread, but that's what solved my issue.

Comment: A few notes *(@BartFriederichs please add some of that to the post)*. First: the `wd_disable` param no longer exists. The `11n_disable=1` did help me, but as others mentioned that somewhat decreases the speed. I'd advice you to try values different from `1`, e.g. `11n_disable=8`, etc. For allowed values and their meaning see `modinfo iwlwifi`. Another note: tinker with your router settings as well. E.g. my router has option to disable `802.11n`. But what really helped me is making router never use 40Mh width. Only 20Mh made it work, so in the end I didn't have to disable `11n` completely.

Comment: In my case, the authentication was successful but the association timed out. Adding the option 11n_disable=1 as mentioned worked! thank you so much

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you to switch to `iwd` as a replacement for `wpa_supplicant` if WiFi speeds are important to you, as disabling 802.11n (as recommended in [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/912284/680651) with the `11n_disable` option) may cause a decrease in network performance in 2.4GHz networks that support 802.11n.

I got this to work on my HP Elitebook 1030 running Manjaro GNOME and am very glad I now get to profit from the entire WiFi bandwidth my home network provides. Before, disabling 802.11n was the only option I knew of. Here goes a little guide on how to get `iwd` up and running instead of `wpa_supplicant`.

### Installation & Setup

Install the required package:

```
sudo dnf install iwd
```

Edit the NetworkManager config (I'm assuming you're running NetworkManager):

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

```
# https://iwd.wiki.kernel.org/networkmanager#nm_configuration
[device]
wifi.backend=iwd
```

The above config will make NetworkManager use `iwd` instead of `wpa_supplicant` which you're having problems with.

We now need to start/stop/restart the required services to get the config loaded and applied.

```
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl start iwd
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

And to make your changes permanent (by having the correct service start on boot and without interfering with the wrong one):

```
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
sudo systemctl enable iwd
```

You should now be able to connect to WiFi networks using the normal GUI. If connecting that way doesn't work for you, try using the `iwctl` command line interface. Connecting to the correct network should work that way. To get an IP-Address assigned, you may need to run the command `dhclient`.

Refer to the Arch Wiki Link below to learn more about `iwd` and `iwctl`. Also refer to the Arch Wiki if you're having issues like getting your password (PSK) to work.

If you can connect to networks successfully, try removing the `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file to re-activate 802.11n on next boot / module reload. This was the point of switching to `iwd`, after all.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

### Sources

Steps taken from [linux-whv.de](https://linux-whv.de/die-neue-wifi-erfahrung-fuer-linux-iwd),
[ArchWiki on iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd)

Comment: Didn't work for me, still "authentication timed out". And I wonder: did that really help to anyone? I find odd if it does, because most of wifi management, I presume, is done by kernel driver. I might be wrong, but this answer is opposed to `11n_disable` kernel module parameter, so at least in that context it is opposing userspace to kernel driver.