# Wifi authentication times out immediately when accessing a particular network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, authentication

My problem is similar to [WiFi authentication times out](https://superuser.com/questions/911635/wifi-authentication-times-out) but that solution didn't work.

This morning my computer was connecting to my home WiFi fine. Now, suddenly, it won't. I get dmesg output like (fake details because I can't copy-paste but you get the idea)

```
[    96.000000] wlan0: authenticate with 9c:31:....
[    96.005000] wlan0: send auth to 9c:31:..... (try 1/3)
[    96.100000] wlan0: send auth to 9c:31:..... (try 2/3)
[    96.150000] wlan0: send auth to 9c:31:..... (try 3/3)
[    96.170000] wlan0: authentication with 9c:31:... timed out
```

This computer cannot connect to my home network either when running Ubuntu or Windows.

The same computer can connect to different WiFi networks.

Other devices can connect to my home network.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Does it help if you down/up the interface? Does restarting the computer or router make any difference?