How to automatically reconnect to WiFi when 'limited' connectivity occurs?
I'm experiencing an issue with my school's WiFi where it stops working every 5 minutes or so. When this happens, nmcli monitor shows "Connectivity is now 'limited'".
I have this short script that automatically reconnects to the wifi when this issue occurs:
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    if nmcli connection show --active | grep -q 'eduroam' \
    && ! ping -c 3 -W 2 google.com &> /dev/null; then
        nmcli connection up eduroam
    fi
    sleep 10
done

While it seems to work fine, I was hoping for a better way. When the connection is limited it takes a while to run (up to ~20 seconds), but I'm reluctant to reduce the ping count or timeout further, to avoid false positives. Perhaps there is some way to have network manager itself trigger the recconection?
Of course, fixing the "Connectivity is now 'limited'" issue would be best, so if you have any ideas on that it would be great. In case it's relevant, I should also mention the wifi doesn't use a captive portal, a CA is required, and the authentication is done through PEAP.
Thank you for your attention!

Is the connection issue due to weak or noisy signal? Try wavemon, for example, to look at details. Fixing it might be as simple as reorienting a machine, or putting a USB wifi dongle on a short cable, or inside a cantenna.

@DrMoishePippik As far as I can tell there are no issues the signal. My suspicion is that the network expects some sort of handshake on some fixed interval (maybe to renew the authentication?). I don't think it's a time interval, but I will time the disconnects and see what I get. I should also add everyone in the building who runs linux has this issue, but afaik the people running windows or mac do not.

That comment is essential -- it really should be in the question, and if you edit it to include that it is a Linux but not Windows issue, you're more likely to get a helpful answer. Perhaps https://superuser.com/questions/911635/wifi-authentication-times-out is the answer?
